# Ember serialize output response

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I want the response to be in this format:

`{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"admin@admin.com"}`

However, this is the response that I'm getting now:

`{"user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"admin@admin.com"}}`

Code: https://github.com/ghoshnirmalya/hub-client

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember has serializes for exactly this purpose. You use its serialize method to format the response the way you want it. Take a look in [ember docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_serialize)

Comment: I've added a serializer but somehow, it is not being called whenever I'm sending the data to the backend.